# Should we always free up Map or List in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Let's say I have a Map. I added a couple of elements, processed those elements and now I no longer need those elements. Should I call `Map#clear();` method or just let garbage collector do its job? Does cleaning the map reduces GC pressure?

Here is a sample code:

```
    public void process() {
        Map<String, Object> myMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        myMap.put("CatA", "Meow1");
        myMap.put("CatB", "Meow2");

        doSomeProcessing(myMap);

        myMap.clear();
    }
```

P.S- This operation will be done around 10K times per second.

Comment: You don't need to do that.... once the reference to myMap is out of scope, all the references that myMap holds will also be out of scope (assuming that you didn't pull one out and keep it in scope somewhere else)... so the end result will be the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `clear` here, as the GC won't treat that as a special signal to garbage collect `myMap`.

Instead, you should make sure that there's no remaining references to `myMap` when `process` finishes executing. Specifically, make sure that `doSomethingElse` doesn't leak the reference for `myMap`.

GC will garbage collect `myMap` once there are no remaining references.